# How to send notifications to the device when the backend is connected to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, flutter

I have a flutter app for both android & IOS , which connects to a wordpress site to pull the posts through wordpress api. I want to add a listener on the wordpress site, such that when a new post is published I would like to send push notifications to the flutter app.

any idea how can i achieve this?

my Approach:

step 1: trigger a function when post is published (https://www.wphub.com/blog/posts/run-a-function-when-post-published/)
this function will submit a post to my firebase database

step 2: firebase realtime event listener will send notifications to mobile

However I am sure there must be better approach to do this?

Comment: You can send your push notification with POST request, is it possible with your  WordPress function?

Comment: @dubace yes I can send POST request from my wordpress function, is there any example you can share?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490629/firebase-send-notification-with-rest-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `publish_post` hook will help you to achieve that. This hook will trigger when the post publishes from the WordPress backend.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'wpse120996_publish_action');
function wpse120996_publish_action($post_id) {

    $post   = get_post( $post_id );
    // Now send the data to firebase via PHP CURL or any suitable medium.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this plugin that could help you achieve this, all you have to do is specify your in the wordpress dashboard, an API Key and a topic  (which your app would subscribe to), to receive notifications.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-firebase-push-notification/

If you'd like to make some customization or see how it works under the hood, here's the link to the plugin code on github.

https://github.com/Clintal/wp-firebase-push-notification/