# How to send push notification to admin to user - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a simple e-commerce app in Flutter. Actually, two apps. 1 for Admin, 2 for users. I implemented push notification using Firebase in Users app. But What I want now is

1. Admin app can send push notification to users app - if any data is added - notification depends on Admin decision.

They can also add data without notification.

I have also used cloud functions, but I don't get any way to send notification from admin to users app. please help, there's lots of tutorials I found but nothing solved my problem, I am a beginner actually.

Comment: is the admin also a mobile app?

Comment: Get *firebase FCM tokens* from user app and store it in your database. You can write an cloud function or just use firebase's inbuilt library provided for android too.  Stack Overflow does not support this types of answers but feel free to watch this series on youtube ```https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPqJcPtN18I&list=PLxefhmF0pcPmtdoud8f64EpgapkclCllj``` and you will understand detailed usage of firebase in android and how to write cloud functions too.

Comment: @javachipper Yes, admin also a mobile app.

Comment: @50_Seconds_Of_Coding Actually, user's app won't authenticate users. Users app just for showing products. When the admin adds data in firestore, they can also decide to send notifications to users. Means all users, not anyone.

Comment: You can do it with fcm through their rest api. 

for you reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490629/firebase-send-notification-with-rest-api

Check out Ashis answer

Comment: Though I don't recommend doing it this way, because it's not efficient. The service for sending the notif is best done in your backend service, this would make it more dynamic in case of any changes and can quickly query the users in your db for a more specific user target.

Comment: @javachipper I checked the page -  stackoverflow you recommended. But as a beginner, I don't know how to implement it in flutter.

Comment: @javachipper I have implemented push notification using cloud functions in a chat app.  But it send notification to all users when cloud firestore updated with new data. But now, Admin app must has the option to update firestore data and also decide push notification needs to send or not.

Comment: Send it using the httpClient package in flutter, or you can use dio which has a ton of features.

Comment: you can send it to an individual user by specifying the device fcm token. So don't forget the firebase packages to be installed in flutter for registering the device.

Comment: Can I get fcm token without authenticating users?

Comment: Yes. It's automatically assigned on the device, if the firebase package is installed. Then you can just retrieve it: var token = await _fcm.getToken(); then send it to your server

Comment: In the admin app, the admin can take data and push it to FireStore. At the same time, there is a checkbox for sending push notification. if he checks it, it will send a push notification while data storing in firestore. otherwise won't. That's what I am going to implement.

Comment: So now I am going to use rest api for sending push notifications. The above scenario, can I use cloud function rather than rest api?