# How to setup push notification with supabase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, supabase

I had just replaced my app with supabase from firebase in flutter app.

Firebase has `firebase_messaging` that provide push notification to device token.

Is there any facilities to create function in supabase and send notification to selected user with device token while changing in database.

If yes than please suggest some function else suggest some method to send notification.

Comment: supabase does not have messaging, as such FCM,onesignal etc are among options available to you

Comment: so what can I do for achieve this without leaving supabase ?

Comment: if you pick FCM, store user tokens in your supabase db, and user functions to send notifications. A firebase account is required for this.

Answer (score 1):

Supabase does not provide a mechanism to send push notifications at this point, so you can use FCM or other push notification sending services to send them out to the users.

If you are going with FCM, you can setup your own backend using Firebase cloud functions or other backend service that you prefer to send the notifications from.

Typically, you would want to send push notifications to your users when there is some kind of change in the database, like when there was a new message sent or someone liked a post. You can listen to these events using [Supabase database webhooks](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-functions-updates#database-webhooks-alpha). With database webhooks, you can send your backend a request whenever you receive certain data change happening in your database.

Comment: Will a notification received to the client is from supabase webhook or FCM ?

Comment: @tailor
In the above setup, the client receives the notification that was sent from FCM. It goes like this: Database change on Supabse -> Trigger database webhooks -> Call backend function -> send FCM from backend function.

Comment: you mean create edge function in supabase ?

Comment: I need some example, if you know than please suggest...!

Comment: @tailor
I guess since you can send FCM via simple Post request, you can use Supabase edge function as well. All you need to do is to call the FCM endpoint from Supabase edge function. You can find out how you can make the API request here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490629/firebase-send-notification-with-rest-api